# Google Chrome tabs freeze and turn white when I try drag them into a separate window

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, freeze, tabs

Google Chrome tabs freeze and turn white when I try drag them into a separate window. I have to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to unfreeze Chrome. I have tried re-installing, it still breaks. I am running Windows 7. I have uploaded a picture of what happens below:

[image: Screenshot of the freezing]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to switch from Chrome to either IE or Firefox.   After enduring Chrome freezes for several months with my Windows 7, I switched to Firefox.
I don't see any reason to switch between browsers.   Just use the one that works well for you.    If you want to synchronize you book marks between multiple browsers (and/or also to make it easy to switch between browsers when needed), use xmarks (at xmarks.com).      Having used xmarks in Chrome, the switch to Firefox was easy

Answer (score 1):

It's probably some app that is not compatible with the latest version of Chrome.
The exact same thing started happening to me 3 days ago, I uninstalled Trusteer (the IBM security app) and it went back to normal.